# Batch file that sync your system time and date

Tags: date, batch-file, time, synchronization

I'm trying to write a batch file that checks the system time and date. I would like it to check over the internet. I have this part. But thinking it should do the  date part. But it only does the time if the date is correct

```
@echo off
w32tm /query /peers 
net stop w32time
net start w32time
w32tm /resync /nowait
EOF
```

I do run the batch file as a administrator.  Can someone help me with the date part of this. Thank you for taking the time to read this post. Any info would be a get help. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You have the NET TIME statement, but surely you don't have XP or a Lower OS, so that statement is already deprecated. For higher versions, therefore, using W32TM is a time management service that also serves to diagnose system problems.

How to synchronize the time and date from CMD?

1. Run a console as Administrator.
2. Start the service: `net start w32time`
3. Check its status: `w32tm /query /peers`
4. Synchronize the time and date: `w32tm /resync /nowait`

You can also change the specific time and date of a computer on the network with: net time \\DOMAIN /set

With this, you can now create the Batch script you need.

On the other hand, for more information, I share the source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/.../windows.../ff799054(v=ws.11)

Answer (score 3):

we push this batch file across networks US and canada via our rmm software

Hope it helps

```
@echo off
w32tm /query /peers
sc config w32time start= auto
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:"0.us.pool.ntp.org,1.us.pool.ntp.org,2.us.pool.ntp.org,3.us.pool.ntp.org"
w32tm /config /reliable:yes
net stop w32time
net start w32time
w32tm /resync /nowait
```

Answer (score 2):

I pulled this out of an email archive from an MCSE friend of mine from 2009, so the information should be fairly close, but may have changed.  I have changed roles pretty significantly since then:

Each windows PDC emulator is the domains time server. If the domains are all in the same forest, you just need to sync the root domains PFC with an atomic external time source. If domains are in separate forests (dmz domain for ex) each PDC emulator needs to be set to look the same set of external atomic clocks. off the top of my head, I use these two in my pool of 5 or so.

Time-a.nist.gov
Time-b.nist.gov

On your PDC run the following:

```
net time /setsntp time-a.nist.gov time-b.nist.gov
```

You need to make sure udp port 123 is allowed outbound from PDC.
all other servers, workstations should have windows time service started.

If you run the following query on a box having trouble and see it set to

> windows.Time.com

or maybe

> time.windows.com

you need to reset it to use domain time. Run the same as above with NO time source:

```
net time /setsntp
```

An invaluable reskit tool to check domain time is w32tm. Run

```
W32tm /monitor
```

If memory serves, Windows 2012 (?) and above, changed the name of the service from W32tm to W32time, so your mileage may vary.

Lastly, if running VMWare esx, you need to make sure all host esx servers are setup to sync to the same external time servers as your windows boxes, using their NTP.conf file. Make sure all vm's are running the latest VM tools and set the tools to sync their time with the esx host. I believe you also stop the windows time service so they do not compete but I'd have to verify. This is true for all VM's but the pdc emulator if running it in a VM. It will not sync with the esx host and should be setup exactly as stated above. Good luck.

Continuing on..
First, I would ask myself..

Do I have PDC (Primary Domain Controller)?

Or, am I just dealing with a bunch of stand-alone workstations on a peer-to-peer network?

You did not state anything about your topology or network.

If you have an NTP server, your clients will connect to it.
Like my good friend stated, you will need to use an NTP  relay that your clients connect to.

He stated: On your PDC (or in a peer-to-peer) setup, you would do the following:

```
net time /setsntp time-a.nist.gov time-b.nist.gov
```

now, moving over to your clients and other member servers, you would do the same thing with the exception of no time servers given, e.g.

```
net time /setsntp
```

as your LAN clients and other member servers will set/synchronize with the PDC several times a day.

So, taking your batch file, I would do something like the following for your PDC (you may also do well to add some SLEEP or PAUSE commands to your Batch File):

```
@echo off
net time /setsntp time-a.nist.gov time-b.nist.gov
w32tm /query /peers 
net stop w32time
net start w32time
w32tm /resync /nowait
EOF
```

And then your workstations and other servers (again, you may also do well to add some SLEEP or PAUSE commands to your Batch File):

```
@echo off
net time /setsntp
w32tm /query /peers 
net stop w32time
net start w32time
w32tm /resync /nowait
EOF
```

I don't know how else to explain this to you as he offered how to do this in bite-sized chunks.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the info. But, still don't know how to add it to my code to make it work better.

Answer (score 0):

for workgroup system. below script is working. time is getting updated as per domain.

```
net stop s32time
w32tm /unregister
w32tm /register
net start w32time
w23 /resync /nowait
w32tm /query /peers
```